# b-tooltip css not working when installing using npm package manager

Tags: vue.js, npm, bootstrap-vue

I am currently working on making a component much like the contribution graph from Github and struggling a bit to share it as an npm package.

The component `vue-contribution-graph` packaged with npm doesn't display the tooltip properly. The CSS for the `b-tooltip`component  is working on the original project but it seems not to be included properly in the packaged component. Indeed, after running `npm i vue-contribution-graph`, the tooltip background doesn't appear.

I have created a GitHub issue just to make it clearer: https://github.com/estelled/vue-contribution-graph/issues/4

The behavior remains the same after installing all the dependencies manually.

I followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/justfrontendthings/how-to-create-and-publish-your-own-vuejs-component-library-on-npm-using-vue-cli-28e60943eed3) for npm packaging.

Files changed to package the component:

1. `package.json`
2. added a `vue.config.js`file, to include CSS in the package

How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you imported the css files of bootstrap and bootstrap-vue in your `main.js`

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it's not working when installing via npm, because the path to the CSS files are wrong. They are, however, correct when running the `vue-contribution-graph` package as standalone.

---

Having looked at your `demo.html`, it looks like it's requiring a missing file: `./vue-contribution-graph.css`. Have you tried setting `extract: false` for your CSS to automatically be included in the bundle?